# Selection criteria for a web application framework

Tags: web-applications, backend, web-frameworks

Assumption:

- A problem is given that should be solved by a web application with backend
- There are several web application frameworks (ruby on rails, jsf,
  play etc.)

What are the criteria for selecting the right one?

- The knowledge of a framework (and the corresponding programming language) is as a criteria uninteresting